# php.ini configuration ignored under Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: php

I am trying to tune my php configuration using the `php.ini` file on a microsoft server 2012 R2 but the value that I set up are ignored.

I write a simple `info.php` page that contains :

```
<?php
phpinfo() ;
```

The `Loaded Configuration File` directive has for value the path of the right `php.ini` file that I am editing.

The Apache service has been restarted successfully but the value displayed by the `info.php` are not the values that I set in the `php.ini` file.

There is no `.htaccess` file.

*Note: this is not a duplicate of [settings-on-php-ini-ignored](https://serverfault.com/questions/406888/settings-on-php-ini-ignored) since the issue does not come from a server restart and I am editing the right `php.ini` file.*

Any idea?

Comment: So this is when you navigate to the page and nothing to do with PHP over CLI? Just to get that question out the way..?

Comment: Yeah, restarting Apache will have no affect on IIS. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: IIS and Apache are two different web servers. Which one are you trying to configure?

Comment: @Dammeul: this is when I look at the https://ip-server/info.php with my web browser not with the CLI

Comment: @Zhorov and delboy1978uk you are right!! I am not familiar with windows and I don't use the right words. We are using  Apache/2.4.28 (Win32) PHP/5.6.31 under Windows Server 2012 R2.